# What is the meaning of "single page apps" in context with "round trip" apps?

Tags: angularjs, terminology

Found here:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/introduction

It states that "You can use Angular to develop both single-page and round-trip apps, but Angular is designed primarily for developing single-page apps. Angular supports browser history, forward and back buttons, and bookmarking in single-page apps."

But I'm not finding much on the two terms, spelled exactly that way, but I did find this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_engineering

Is this the correct term?

Comment: I suggest you look at this answer for better explanation. I found this answer the best.    https://stackoverflow.com/a/33993523/1999190

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Single page app, everything happens on one "page", although the URL might change.  Most state changes are shown to the user without going to the server (they'll go to the server for data, but not html/js/css etc)

Round-trip apps are apps that change pages on every get/post/put request.  The round trip is the path the application takes from the browser, to the server, to the browser to display every change in state to the user.  This usually results in "flicker" as the web browser has to redraw every page.

Round-trip engineering is a different beast.

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation it should be added to the wiki, imho.  Why am I surprised to find out that angular isn't best suited for round-trip apps?  All that data binding goodness seems to fall perfectly under a round-trip apps purvue

Comment: So could an application whose view changes constantly due to user interaction with the server also be considered a single page app?  I just spoke with a teammate of mine and he is telling me some conflicting information.  He said that the definition has more to do with where the HTML is compiled/parsed (updated).

Comment: Round Trip generates HTML on the server, single page all HTML is on the page.

Comment: A single page app only asks for data (usually in json format), and then renders appropriately.