# AngularJS is perfect for Single Page Applications what is the meaning?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS is perfect for Single Page Applications (SPAs). I'm new to angularjs and this is the first statement I came across. What does this mean?

Comment: You want to know the meaning of SPA ?

Comment: @kikuyu1 It means that you can navigate to any route/page without completely loading/reloading the whole page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**SPA** is a Single Page Application where the browser loads the entire page once and refreshes part(s) of the page based on the request by the user during interaction.

**Now we will look AngularJS Advantages,**

**Two-way-Data Binding:** When ever data is changed the view automatically refreshes which means we don't need to load the entire page again.

**Controllers:** You can confine your logic only to particular part of the view using controllers. Which makes the view scope refer to only particular controller. This is brillinat way to control SPA.

**Services:** 
These are singleton objects which are instantiated only once when the application loads.

**Directives:** Directives are custom widgets. We create them once and use them where ever we need.

**Routing:** Switching views based on the user request.

**Dependency Injection:** AngularJS has a built-in dependency injection. You just need to say what you need and angular will arrange you that. A simple example is when you need severice functionalities in your Controller then just inject you service in your controller and proceed with the business logic.

**MVC:** Using AngularJS we can have Model, View, Controller architecture on the client side.

and many more.

These are some of the reasons why AngularJS is perfect for Single Page Applications.

Refer this wonderful [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvHecQOiu8g) for more details on SPA and AngularJS.

Comment: Excellent explanation

Answer (score 1):

Technically SPA means the page does not reload at any point in the process, nor does control transfer to another page.

Using MVC structure of angular JS you may develop your application in such a way that it behaves like a SPA.

Answer (score 0):

That is, when you wants make web site which contains only one page (we call it as lending page), angular-JS works well. For example, download any web editor ( I recommand IUEditor ) , make 'angular-js' framework, and build it. Than angular-js web site will be generated, and you can use it. That is the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

A [single page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) is a style of web development where the developer loads only a single page at first. That is it.

Now that we know our app is only a single page, how then would we have all the dynamism of an app? That's where frameworks like Angular come in.

Take the below example for illustration -- we have an application that magically updates the greeting text based on user input (DOM is being changed)

To summarize, the below example is a single page app:

- It takes some user input
- Does something and re-renders the DOM
- All in a single page

More complicated examples would use controllers, and such. I'd really recommend you spend time with a tutorial, like the one at http://www.freecodecamp.com/map#angularjs

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```